# Can enums be non static?

Tags: java, enums, static

I have the following public enum:

```
public enum CommandObject {
    STRING/*etc.*/;
    private Collection<String> validOptions = new ArrayList<>();

    protected Collection<String> getValidOptions() {
        return validOptions;
    }

    protected boolean hasValidOptions() {
        return !validOptions.isEmpty();
    }

    protected CommandObject addValidOption(String option) {
        validOptions.add(option);
        return this;
    }

    public static CommandObject argsetOf(String... args) {
        CommandObject result = STRING;
        for (String option : args) {
            result.addValidOption(option);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

but it seems, that `getValidOptions()` returns always the same collection no matter what instance I call.

For example when calling `argsetOf("hi")` and `argsetOf("bye")` the collection always consists of `["hi","bye"]`.

Does somebody know any workaround for this? I need this enum to have a "non static" attribute.

It doesn't need to be an enum, but should still be simple to use.

Comment: No. Enums are always implicitly static.

Comment: @AndyTurner workarounds?

Comment: Any reason you do not want to use one of the existing command line parsing libraries?

Comment: You made argsetOf() as static. It ain't gonna work as you wish being static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enums are always static, implicitly.

A workaround here might be to store the collections externally to the enum, e.g. a non-static map externally to the enum, with the enum values as keys:

```
Map<CommandObject, Collection<String>>
```

Then you can have as many separate instances of this map as you like, but are still associating the collections with a particular enum value.

Comment: Is this going to work when adding `STRING` multiple times?

Comment: Adding `STRING` to what multiple times?

Comment: to this Map... Whatever found a better solution myself... having this attribute in a class using the enum